# R - using heatmaply for a 2d histogram / density

Tags: r, visualization, data-wrangling, heatmaply

I'm rather new to programming and the site so let me know if I screw up on this explanation.

I have a rather long series of x, y coordinates representing a character in 2d space. Let's say that space is 200 x 400. I want to represent the amount of time the character is in each x, y coordinate by means of a pretty chloropleth.

I want to use heatmaply for this because I think the output is pretty and I want my audience to be able to zoom in on the data. It isn't really meant to do density estimation (I think?) so I'm trying to work around it.

I suppose the way to do this is to fill a 200x400 dataframe with counts of the number of occurrences of each x, y coordinate in the data at each x, y coordinate in the frame. Essentially, to build a 2d map out of the data frame and impose the counts upon it

So, I suppose my questions are:

1). How do I get the count of each unique x, y coordinate in my set

2). How might I pass those counts easily to the matching x, y cell in my 200x400 dataframe full of zeroes?

This seems like it should be easy but I can't seem to figure it out! I'm a novice to r and can't see the shape of what I need to do.

Comment: Please post a sample data to help us better understand the dimension and characteristics of your data.

Comment: Just a simple  dataframe where range of x is 0-200 and range of y is 0-400, representing the character being in location x, y https://pastebin.com/BL3NSf2i

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `table` function to get your matrix of counts.

```
table(X,Y)
```

X and Y should be columns of coordinates.

Output based on some sample data
[image]

Comment: That's it. I'm baffled at my inability to Google that solution.

Comment: Please close your question by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer if it resolved you query. Have a nice day :)